# How to center one sign text inside span?

Tags: html, css, center

I have example span with text. Text in this case includes only one sign. As you can see, text isn't centered. Second text "2B" isn't centered too. I've tried centering by:

- display flex
- text-align

[image]

[image]

html:

```
<span class="d-flex justify-content-between">1&nbsp;</span>
```

css:

```
border: 2px solid #f07d00;
border-radius: 20px;
position: relative;
background-color: #fff;
text-align: center;
color: #0f1c2e;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 13px #EF7F1A33;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 600;

padding: 3px 4px;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a [mre]?

Comment: if you put a non breaking space after the text, it's always going to be pushed a bit to the left and also have you tried `justify-content-center` instead of between?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
PHP templates injected into values non breaking space after text. I didn't noticed it untiled I published this post. Helped only copying html code from browser and a hint @Pete (Thank you). Looking only to browser inspector, the problem is not noticeable as on this image.
[image]